# Cannot transfer a list:The underlying connection was closed

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, entity-framework, webclient

I'm having a trouble passing a list inside an object in WCF service. I have this class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Field
{
    /*Necessary Information*/
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String Picture { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double TypicalAge { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Report> ReportHistory { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Report
{
    [DataMember]
    public long ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public ReportTypes Type { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int FieldID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String Head { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String Body { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

When the list of reports is empty or size of 1, everything works.
When the list size is **bigger than 1**, I get this error:

`The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly..`

The code in the server:

```
public List<Field> GetFieldsByIDs(List<int> listOfIDs)
    {
        var result = new List<Field>();
        using (var context = new FieldBookEntities())
        {
            var fields = context.FieldEntities.Where(x => listOfIDs.Contains(x.ID)).Select(FieldEntityToField).ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < listOfIDs.Count; i++)
            {
                var field = fields.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == listOfIDs.ElementAt(i));
                if (field != null)
                    result.Add(field);
            }
        }



        return result;
    }
```

The code in the client:

```
 client = new FieldServiceClient();
 var fieldsByIDs = client.GetFieldsByIDs(new int[] { 1, 2 });
```

The interface:

```
public interface IFieldService
{

    [OperationContract]
    bool CheckConnection();


    [OperationContract]
    List<Field> GetFieldsByIDs(List<int> listOfIDs); //max 30 fields
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: Show the code that errors.

Comment: Why do you pass an `int[]` and not a `List<int>`

Comment: The server somehow asks for an array.
It doesnt matter, because I get the full list to the server

Comment: Could you add your service interface

Comment: I fixed the problem.
The information in the DB wan't like in the enum, so changing it to numbers like in the enum fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. The information in the DB wan't like in the enum, so changing it to numbers like in the enum fixed it. not a code problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

after

```
using (var context = new FieldBookEntities())
{
```

Also, change the following:

```
var fields = context.FieldEntities.Where(x => listOfIDs.Contains(x.ID)).Select(FieldEntityToField).ToList();
```

To:

```
var fields = context.FieldEntities.Include("ReportHistory").Where(x => listOfIDs.Contains(x.ID)).Select(FieldEntityToField).ToList();
```

Comment: Didn't work!.After I did it(context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;), the context returns empty list of reports in the Server! So anyway the clients gets an empty list, while removing this line there are 7 reports. try passing those reports give me the error above.

Comment: Amended my answer - does this sort it?

Comment: Well, It fixed the Reports that was missing in the server.
But still doesn't work! I still get the error when the client try to get answer from the function.